# img src is not displaying inside ngFor loop

Tags: html, typescript, ionic4

I have some code intended to show the default user profile image or the profile image that the user has just uploaded, however the default image doesn't display in the div, and only after the user uploads their own profile image, does their image display.

I can see the default image by its self outside of the grid.

```
<ion-content>
 <ion-grid style ="text-align: center">
  <ion-row >
 <ion-col *ngFor="let item of students" >
     <div  class= "imageHold" >
         <img [src]= "profileImage"> 
     </div>
 </ion-col>  
</ion-row >
<ion-row  style ="text-align: center">  
    <ion-col>
 <ion-button  size="small" fill="outline" (click)="chooseProfilePic()" >Choose Profile Photo</ion-button>
</ion-col>
</ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

TS

```
this.profileImage =  ["./assets/imgs/user.png"];
    this.profileService.read_Students().subscribe(data => {

      this.students = data.map(e => {
        return {
          id: e.payload.doc.id,
          isEdit: false,
          userName: e.payload.doc.data()['userName'],
          userBio: e.payload.doc.data()['userBio'],
          profileImage: e.payload.doc.data()['profileImage'],
        };
      })
      console.log(this.students);

    });

  }
```

firebase snippet in ts

```
  this.firebaseService.uploadImage(image_src, randomId)
    .then(photoURL => {
      this.profileImage = photoURL;
      loading.dismiss();
      toast.present();
    }, err =>{
      console.log(err);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Isn't it looking at `this.students.profileImage` and you stored default at `this.profileImage`?

Comment: use ionImg for the ionic angular purpose.refer this link https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't profileImage be a string instead of array?
Like this:

`this.profileImage = "./assets/imgs/user.png";?`

And also according Ionic docs you should use:
`<ion-img [src]="profileImage"></ion-img>`